# Searching for data in two lists player a & player b is the same as player b & player a

Tags: excel, office365, vlookup

I have two lists of data one has all the pairings (column A) one has my pairings for the next week (column B).

I am using vlookup `=VLOOKUP(B2,$A$2:$A$191,1,FALSE)` to compare the two lists which is working correctly as its showing the names that appear the way in the search list. However some pairings do not appear for example Player A & Player B but in my search list its Player B & Player A.

Is there a function / formula that will allow for both as I have tried a wild card to no avail.

Comment: So you literally have an ampersand and you want that to be the delimiter for splitting the data?  And there is only ever one ampersand in a cell?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah   Yes that is correct. The ampersand is there to join the pairs together. I would like cell C to show if PlayerA&PlayerB or PlayerB&Player are in Column A show TRUE or the value in Column B.